# AlertDialog с помощью RxJava

Tags: android, rxjava

С помощью AsyncTask при обработке массива данных мы легко можем вывести с помощью AlertDialog прогресс выполнения обработки.

Можно ли это сделать с помощью RxJava? Прошу вашего простейшего примера.

И как решается проблема поворота девайса при загрузке данных с сервера при помощи RxJava и отображения прогресса на AlertDialog?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29959083/1991579

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой способ это заюзать метод from:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        list.add("item "+i);
    }

    Observable.from(list)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            if(progress!=null && progress.isShowing()) progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            if(progress!=null && progress.isShowing()) progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            progress =  ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
                    "dialog message", true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете при каждой итерации создавать, показывать и удалять диалоговое окно?

Comment: SmallSani, это приведено в качестве примера, суть вопроса заключалась в другом

Comment: Хорошо. Как пример он подходит. Однако заметил, что проблему поворота девайса он не решает. Итерация начинается заново. Есть мысли по этому поводу? Спасибо!

Comment: SmallSani, Посмотрите статью: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html